# How do I exclude duplicates entries in a CSV-file from being importing into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a CSV file with many duplicate entries. How do I import the entries into MySQL without also importing the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define one of the columns (one where you are sure that there will be duplicate data) as UNIQUE in MySQL, and then import everything and just let the DB spit out errors in the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code for  import the entries into MySQL without also importing the duplicates and count the number of records and number of duplicate

```
<?php
$duplicate=0;
$record=0;
$total=0;
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","rootpass","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("svn",$conn);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$handle=fopen($file,"r");
while(($fileop=fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
{
if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
$fn= addslashes ($fileop[0]);
$ln=addslashes ($fileop[1]);
$ti=addslashes ($fileop[2]);
$ac=addslashes ($fileop[3]);
$em=addslashes ($fileop[4]);
$op=addslashes ($fileop[5]);
$mp=addslashes ($fileop[6]);
$fx=addslashes ($fileop[7]);
$ad=addslashes ($fileop[8]);
$co=addslashes ($fileop[9]);
$st=addslashes ($fileop[10]);
$ci=addslashes ($fileop[11]);
$zc=addslashes ($fileop[12]);
}
else
{
$fn= $fileop[0];
$ln=$fileop[1];
$ti=$fileop[2];
$ac=$fileop[3];
$em=$fileop[4];
$op=$fileop[5];
$mp=$fileop[6];
$fx=$fileop[7];
$ad=$fileop[8];
$co=$fileop[9];
$st=$fileop[10];
$ci=$fileop[11];
$zc=$fileop[12];
}


$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE email='$em'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
  {

   $duplicate=$duplicate+1;
  }
else
  {
  $record=$record+1;
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(first_name,last_name,title,account,email,officephone,mobphone,fax,address,country,state,city,zipcode) 
VALUES('$fn','$ln','$ti','$ac','$em','$op','$mp','$fx','$ad','$co','$st','$ci','$zc')");
}
}

echo"Data inserted successfully";

echo "<table width='600' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' border='1'>";
echo "<tr>"."<td>"."Record inserted"."</td>"."<td>".$record."</td>"."</tr>";
echo "<tr>"."<td>"."duplicate record"."</td>"."<td>".$duplicate."</td>"."</tr>";
echo "<tr>"."<td>"."Total records"."</td>"."<td>".$total=$record + $duplicate."</td>"."</tr>";
echo "</table>";


}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?
$duplicate=0;
$record=0;
$total=0;
?>
</head>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" value="selectfile"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```